# How to always show hint text in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, textfield, mask

I am trying to create a text field that has hintText which would not disappear after I start typing. The dashes of the phone mask should not disappear when I start typing. [hint text with phone mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFQxB.gif)